# Maximum number of times this loop executes

Tags: java

I have this for loop and I am preparing for an exam. I want to see how many times this loop executes.
without knowing the value of K and somevalue, how can we determine the number of times SMALL is printed. The book answer says it is K-1.

```
 for(int i=2; i<= k; i++)
     if(arr[i]< someValue)
        System.out.println("SMALL");
```

Comment: Is there any additional info about `arr`?

Comment: You can determine the number of times the loop runs (Assuming it doesn't stop with an Exception because of an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds or similar), but without knowing anything about arr and someValue it is impossible to determine how many times SMALL is printed.

Comment: Does the book mean maximum number of times? Maybe then it would make sense.

Comment: You are asking 2 different things: the number of times the loop iterates and the number of times the word "SMALL" is printed. Which is it?

Answer (score 2):

If it were simply

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
```

The **loop** would run `k` times since you are starting at `0` but not reaching `k`

- So add `2` to the starting point you get `k-2` times
- add back in `1` because it is `<=` and you get `k-1` times.

It tends to get a little less obvious when the increment isn't `1`

Note:  That is how many times the loop will execute.  The number of times `SMALL` will print can't be determined without more information.

Comment: *"The number of times `SMALL` will print can't be determined"* Ahh, but according to the question *title*, we don't want to know how many times it *will* print, but the **maximum** number of times it *could* print, which of course would be when the `if` condition is always true.

Comment: @Andreas Good point!   This question should, imo, be about loop iteration and not clouded with the conditional.  Just put a print statement in there.

Comment: If this is an exercise in learning about Big-O, then it is trying to show how things like conditional logic gets eliminated when looking for worst case (maximum) scenarios. The `if` statement could therefore be a huge part of the exercise, which is why it is there.

Answer (score 1):

in this case `somevalue` doesn't matter, you can calculate the count of executed loop your self by using another variable, use this:

```
int count = 0;

for (int i = 2; i <= k; i++) {

    if (arr[i] < someValue) {
        System.out.println("SMALL");
    }

    count++;
}

System.out.println("this for loop executed: " + count + " times.");
```

Answer (score 1):

The question needs more inputs because without the values of `arr[]` and `somevalue`, we cannot find the answer.
However, since the loop starts at 2 and runs till its equal to `k`, we can say that it will run till `k` times `-1` (since loop starts 2 for `a <= condition` instead of the usual 1), which translates to `k-1` executions of the loop.

Still it doesn't guarantee the number of times `"SMALL"` will be printed. That is only possible if all values in the array `arr` are less than `somevalue`